# How to use stylesheet_link_tag with sprockets 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets

I have file app/assets/stylesheets/themes/plexa/home.sass

1. Added to config/manifest.js

   //= link themes/plexa/home.css
2. Check `http://localhost:3000/assets/themes/plexa/home.css` - It works, I see css!
3. But if I add to rails layout:

`stylesheet_link_tag "themes/plexa/home"` This doesn't work!

**It raise rails exception: ActionView::Template::Error at /
themes/plexa/home.css**

Tried with debugger:

```
byebug) stylesheet_link_tag "themes/plexa/home"
*** Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled Exception: themes/plexa/home.css
```

I read all sprockets docs and upgrade guide but doesn't understand why stylesheet_link_tag doesn't works ( Rails 5.1)

**Update:** = stylesheet_link_tag "/assets/themes/plexa/home" **Works, but I doesn't understand why I need to setup assets path?**

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Sprockets has not been updated that's why manifest.js ignored because there is an old ruby version 2.4.6, which need to update